# Will rustc enable frame pointers on linux by default?

Tags: linux, rust, llvm

The [rustc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#force-frame-pointers) indicates that

> The default behaviour, if frame pointers are not force-enabled, depends on the target

What is the default behavior on linux, and how can I find the default value for all targets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look through the rustc-code, it looks as [linux is defaulted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f02439dea78e5c2df42198c7a03e2db6002ff263/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/mod.rs#L1852) to [FramePointer::MayOmit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nightly-rustc/rustc_target/spec/enum.FramePointer.html)

> Allows the machine code generator to omit the frame pointers. This option does not guarantee that the frame pointers will be omitted.

This [corresponds to](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f02439dea78e5c2df42198c7a03e2db6002ff263/compiler/rustc_codegen_llvm/src/attributes.rs#L114) llvm's `frame-pointer` [function attribute](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html?highlight=frame-pointer#function-attributes) with a value of `none`. So it leaves it up to llvm to decide on a per-function basis.

You can see all the platform defaults in [rust/src/librustc_target/spec/](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/f02439dea78e5c2df42198c7a03e2db6002ff263/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec).

Comment: Thank you very much! So may I understand that like this "some function will have frame pointer, and some will not"?

Comment: @PureWhite seems that way. The attribute makes [DisableFramePointerElim](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/c0318f079a0c7a0558c29f04b4e190277f6f6687/llvm/lib/CodeGen/TargetOptionsImpl.cpp#L38) `false`, then for `x86` it seems to take [quite a few things into concideration](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/c0318f079a0c7a0558c29f04b4e190277f6f6687/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86FrameLowering.cpp#L97) on if a function should have a frame pointer.